# Radio Buttons and Event check in an If statment c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write an *If* statement inside a `graphicsPanel1_Paint` method where the paint should only happen when a certain radio button is selected and a button is clicked.

Here is my current code:

```
private void graphicsPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int x = 0; x < mapSize.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapSize.Height; y++)
            {
                Rectangle destRect = Rectangle.Empty;
                destRect.X = x * tileSize.Width;
                destRect.Y = y * tileSize.Height;
                destRect.Size = tileSize;

                destRect.X += graphicsPanel1.AutoScrollPosition.X;
                destRect.Y += graphicsPanel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y;

                Rectangle srcRect = Rectangle.Empty;
                srcRect.X = map[x, y].X * tileSize.Width;
                srcRect.Y = map[x, y].Y * tileSize.Height;
                srcRect.Size = tileSize;

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.colors, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                buttonUse.Click += buttonUse_Click;

                if (radioButtonColor.Checked == true)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.colors, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    graphicsPanel1.Invalidate();
                }

                else if (radioButtonDesert.Checked == true)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.desert9x8x32x32, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    graphicsPanel1.Invalidate();
                }

                else if (radioButtonEarth.Checked == true)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources._default, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    graphicsPanel1.Invalidate();
                }

                else if (radioButtonMagic.Checked == true)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.super4x4x64x64, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    graphicsPanel1.Invalidate();
                }

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, destRect);
            }
        }
    }
```

Obviously, this does not work.

Comment: write a button click event, and inside that function check if that radio button is checked or not.

Comment: In your `buttonUse.Click()` event check the `if(radioButtonColor.Checked) ` and write the code.

Comment: ...and where did you write this code?

Comment: If the button is supposed to have a toggle behavior, either write that into the button's event handler, or just turn it into a checkbox which has a `Checked` property.

Comment: If the click of the button force the paint?? or is a checker (like the other comments asked about?)?? it's not totally clear what the form has to do or how it has to react..

Comment: @gbianchi Yes. I would like it to force the as soon as the radio button is selected and the button is pressed.

Comment: well the things can't happen at the same time.. when the user press the button or when the user check? what if the user press the button and not check? what if the user check and never press the button??

Comment: @gbianchi The way my map editor is set up is, it starts off with a default tile set and if you want to use a different tile set, you have to select the corresponding radio button and push the button. Does this help ?

Comment: yes @Eric, now that's the kind of info you should has write on the question.. now you have to invalidate the graphic panel when you press the button, so it re paint itself.

Comment: @gbianchi Thank you for your patience and helping me understand more proper ways of asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a global variable to check for a clicked button (or toggled states), then add an event handler to the `buttonUse` and `OnPaint` and use  this code:

```
bool btnUsePressed = false; // Declare a variable to track pressed button
buttonUse.Click += new EventHandler(this.buttonUse_Click); // e.g. in the Form_Load() 

// and then
private void graphicsPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // ... YOU CODE UP TO
    if (radioButtonColor.Checked == true && btnUsePressed)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.colors, destRect, srcRect,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        graphicsPanel1.Invalidate();
    }
    // ... YOU CODE AFTER
}

void buttonUse_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnUsePressed)
       btnUsePressed = false;
    else
    {
       btnUsePressed = true;
       graphicsPanel1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: `EventArgs` does not expose a `Graphics` property.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: `System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs`, now OK?

Comment: Well, nope. Click handlers are invoked with an `EventArgs` argument, so that code will not compile. You would have to handle both events for this solution to make sense.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: The problem is that OP does not provide more context :(

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Not answering questions like this one may not be such a bad idea.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't provide more context. I have updated the code to show more of whats going on. This is my very post on this site, so excuse my lack of knowledge of the ins and outs of the site.

Comment: @Eric: Please check the approach suggested.

Comment: Altough using a global (?) variables that just can be declare at form level, is not really appeling, what if the user want to unpress the button??

Comment: @stribizhev It works but only if I click back on the form window. I was looking for it to change as soon as the button was pressed.

Comment: @Eric: Please retry with `graphicsPanel1.Refresh();` in the `buttonUsed_Click`. Edit: I refactored all the names related to Button to "btnUse".

Comment: Great, I would like to also note that `btnUsePressed` can be set to `false` right in the `if` block.

Answer (score -1):

Click() is an event so you would need to handle that event and then check your radio button. So something like

```
buttonUse.Click()+= buttonUse_Click  
void buttonUse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (radioButtonColor.Checked == true)
    {
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.colors, destRect,     srcRect,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
     graphicsPanel1.Invalidate();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can someone please tell me why I got down voted so I can fix it for next time?

Comment: Probably the same reason as in my comment to the other answer -- that code will not compile. Check your syntax and the properties of `RoutedEventArgs`.